# Dragging a SOUTH container is incorrectly propagated to an underlying element in the CENTER container

Tags: codenameone

I have a BorderLayout contentPane. In CENTER there is a list of elements which are all SwipeableContainer, in SOUTH, there is another SwipeableContainer. The SOUTH container is of course 'on top of' the CENTER list, but even then, when I swipe the SOUTH Swipeable, the underlying (half hidden) Swipeable is also swiped. So, it seems that the drag events are propagated to the below list even though the shouldn't.

The below example illustrates it: run the code and drag the "SOUTH CONTAINER" left, and the "ListElement" container below it will also swipe left.

To be sure to see the problem, swipe at the *top* of the SOUTH CONTAINER (so the pointer is also above the lowest visible ListElement), otherwise it could be the completely hidden ListElement that is swiped.

I guess this is a bug (I don't think the drag should affect an element which is partially 'hidden' below the visually dragged element), but if it's not, I'd appreciate input on how to avoid it since it is visually very disturbing.

```
//TEST: SWIPEABLE CONTAINER ALSO SWIPES UNDERLYING CONTAINER AS WELL
  Form hi = new Form("Welcome", new BorderLayout());
  Container list = new Container(BoxLayout.y());
  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
     SwipeableContainer swip = new SwipeableContainer(null, new Label("SWIPE"), new SpanLabel("ListElement " + i + " + a lot of fill text to make the element span over several lines so the dragging of the underlying Swipeable is normally noticeable"));
    list.add(swip);
  }
  list.setScrollableY(true);
  Container cont = hi.getContentPane();
  cont.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, list);
  SwipeableContainer swip = new SwipeableContainer(null, new Label("SOUTHSWIPE"), new Label("SOUTH CONTAINER"));
  cont.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, swip);
  hi.show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug but looking at the code I'm hard pressed on how to fix that as the code didn't foresee this sort of layout. We'll probably need to create a special case for dealing with this type of layout. I suggest filing an issue in the issue tracker with the test case code.

Comment: Thanks, I create the issue, and added a thought on how it might be resolved